# STS (Springsource Tool Suite) freezes for some seconds

Tags: freeze, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using STS 3.1.0 based on Eclipse 4.2.1 and I was having an annoying problem: it froze when I changed the active editor tab.

To solve that, I've edited *artifacts.xml* (you can find it in your STS installation folder), searched for *firefox* and commented the two found entries related to firefox (I found two, maybe you have just one or more than two). After that my STS doesn't freeze longer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but on StackOverflow, this is a question and answer format.  Next time, you should phrase your problem as a question, and then answer it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you explain why this works?